# vscode autocomplete class functions

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to make VSCODE autocomplete class functions in python?
when I create the constructor it works but if I simply type def someName() it won't add the self parameter automatically.
Is there a way to enable it?

Comment: find the removed python snippets, multiple questions here on SO about this, it has a snippet for a class def

Answer (score 0):

`File` > `Preferences` (Code > Preferences on macOS) -> `User Snippets`, and then select the language python for which the snippets should appear.

```
  "def": {
    "prefix": "def function",
    "body": ["def ${1:name}(self${2:,}):", "\t$0"],
    "description": "definition a function"
  },
```